# Orientação por objetos - como utilizar método para extrair coluna

Tags: python

Oi! Estou começando no Python e estou presa nesse exercício. Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? Preciso criar uma classe herdando de um arquivo.txt:
Crie a classe `ArquivoCSV`. Ela deve extender (herdar) a classe `ArquivoTexto` para reaproveitar os seus atributos (`self.arquivo` e `self.conteudo`) e método (`self.extrair_linha`). Além disso, adicione o seguinte atributo:

- `self.colunas`: Atributo do tipo `list` onde os elementos são os nome das colunas;
  A classe também deve conter o seguinte método:
- `self.extrair_coluna_da_linha`: Método que recebe como parâmetro o numero da linha e o indice da coluna e retorna o valor em questão.

Fiz esse código mas não deu certo, somente a Classe Pai

```
class Arquivo_csv(ArquivoTexto):
  def __init__(self, arquivo: str):
      super().__init__(arquivo=arquivo)
      self.colunas = self.extrair_coluna_da_linha()
  
  def extrair_coluna_da_linha(self, numero_linha: int, numero_coluna: int):
    colunas = list()
    for linha in self.conteudo:
      conteudo_linha=linha.strip().split(sep=',')
      colunas.append(conteudo_linha[numero_linha, numero_coluna])
      colunas.pop(0)
    return colunas

---> Classe Pai
class ArquivoTexto():
  def __init__(self,arquivo:str):
    self.arquivo=arquivo
    self.conteudo=self._extrair_conteudo()

  def _extrair_conteudo(self):
    conteudo=None
    with open(file=self.arquivo,mode='r',encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
      conteudo=arquivo.readlines()
      return conteudo
  def _extrair_linha(self,numero_linha:int):
   return self.conteudo[numero_linha-1]
```

Aparece um erro : TypeError: extrair_coluna_da_linha() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'numero_linha' and 'numero_coluna'
deveria retornar esses valores:

```
arquivo_csv = Arquivo_csv(arquivo='carros.csv')

numero_linha = 1
print(arquivo_csv._extrair_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha)) # id,valor_venda,valor_manutencao,portas,pessoas,porta_malas

numero_linha = 10
print(arquivo_csv._extrair_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha)) # 9,low,med,2,2,small

print(arquivo_csv.colunas) # ['id', 'valor_venda', 'valor_manutencao', 'portas', 'pessoas', 'porta_malas']

numero_linha = 10
numero_coluna = 2
print(arquivo_csv.extrair_coluna_da_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha, numero_coluna=numero_coluna)) # low
```

os arquivos são esses:

```
%%writefile musica.txt
Roda Viva
Chico Buarque

Tem dias que a gente se sente
Como quem partiu ou morreu
A gente estancou de repente
Ou foi o mundo então que cresceu
A gente quer ter voz ativa
No nosso destino mandar
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega o destino pra lá

Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião

O tempo rodou num instante
Nas voltas do meu coração
A gente vai contra a corrente
Até não poder resistir
Na volta do barco é que sente
O quanto deixou de cumprir
Faz tempo que a gente cultiva
A mais linda roseira que há
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega a roseira pra lá

Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião

%%writefile carros.csv
id,valor_venda,valor_manutencao,portas,pessoas,porta_malas
1,vhigh,med,2,2,small
2,med,vhigh,2,2,small
3,low,vhigh,2,2,small
4,low,high,2,2,small
5,low,high,2,2,small
6,low,high,4,4,big
7,low,high,4,4,big
8,low,med,2,2,small
9,low,med,2,2,small
10,low,med,2,2,small
11,low,med,4,4,big
12,low,low,2,2,small
13,low,low,4,4,small
14,low,low,4,4,med
```

Answer (score -1):

Tive um pouco de dificuldade com esse exercicio, resolvi compartilhar aqui..

```
class ArquivoTexto(object):

  def __init__(self, arquivo: str):
    self.arquivo = arquivo
    self.conteudo = self._extrair_conteudo()

        
  def _extrair_conteudo(self):
      conteudo = list()
      with open(file=self.arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:  ##Importando o arquivo
       conteudo = arquivo.read().splitlines()  ##Extraindo o conteudo do arquivo na variável "conteudo"
       return conteudo

  def extrair_linha(self,numero_linha):  ##Função para extrair linha
      return self.conteudo[numero_linha-1]  ##Extraindo linha da variável "conteudo"


class ArquivoCSV(ArquivoTexto):  ##Criando a Classe que Herdará de ArquivoTXT

  def __init__(self, arquivo: str):  ##Funçao que iniciará a classe Pai
      super().__init__(arquivo=arquivo)  ##Iniciando a Classe Pai, onde arquivo recebe o arquivo da classe Pai

      self.colunas = self.extrair_colunas()  ##Atributo da Sub-Classe
   
  def extrair_colunas(self):  ##Função para extrair coluna da variável "conteudo" 
      return self.conteudo[0]

  def extrair_coluna_da_linha(self, numero_linha: int, numero_coluna: int):  ##Função para Extrair coluna da linha
    num_linha = self.conteudo[numero_linha]  ##1° Buscamos a linha de "conteudo"
    num_linha = num_linha.split(sep=',')[numero_coluna -1]  ##2° Fizemos Split separado por "," e atribuímos a chave -1.
    return num_linha  ##retornamos a "num_linha"
```

Answer (score -2):

Oi tudo bem? Estou no mesmo exercício que você. Eu consegui retornar o valor "low", o último la do exemplo debaixo, mas to tentando até agora mexer no **self.colunas** e não consigo de jeito nenhum. Segue meu código ainda imcompleto por esse erro, espero ajudar.

```
class ArquivoCSV(ArquivoTexto):

  def __init__(self, arquivo: str):

    super().__init__(arquivo=arquivo)
    self.colunas = list()

  def extrair_coluna_da_linha(self, numero_linha: int, numero_coluna: int):
    for linha in self.conteudo:
      self.coluna = self.conteudo.split(',')
    return self.coluna[numero_coluna - 1]
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui.

class ArquivoCSV(ArquivoTexto):
def **init**(self, arquivo: str):
super().**init**(arquivo=arquivo)
self.colunas = self._extrair_nome_colunas()

def _extrair_conteudo(self):
return super()._extrair_conteudo()

def _extrair_nome_colunas(self):
return self.conteudo[0].strip().split(sep=',')

def extrair_coluna(self, indice_coluna: str):
coluna = list()
for linha in self.conteudo:
conteudo_linha = linha.strip().split(sep=',')
coluna.append(conteudo_linha[indice_coluna])
coluna.pop(0)
return coluna

arquivo_csv = ArquivoCSV(arquivo='carros.csv')

numero_linha = 1
print(arquivo_csv.extrair_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha))

numero_linha = 10
print(arquivo_csv.extrair_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha))

indice_coluna = 2
print(arquivo_csv.extrair_coluna(indice_coluna=indice_coluna))